# Can a solar eclipse be directly overhead?

Tags: the-moon

I have trouble picturing eclipses and whether the moon can be directly overhead.

Comment: Define "directly overhead" -- presumably you mean Elevation of 90 degrees from your point of view?

Comment: The sun is *always* overhead *somewhere* on Earth.  So it must be overhead during eclipses, too.

Comment: @MarkOlson well, that does not need to be the place where the moon's umbra (or even the penumbra) is.

Comment: @Glorfindel Fair enough, but some eclipses are central and those will be overhead somewhere.  I don't *think* the questions was where all eclipses must be overhead somewhere, but whether any are.

Comment: When I first travelled to the tropics, I was expecting to see the Sun directly overhead at some point.  I hadn't thought about the Moon.  I experienced this first and was surprised for a moment before  thinking: well, of course, that was going to happen as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They could be directly overhead if you live in the tropics.

The tropics are the regions near the equator, between 23 degrees North and 23 degrees south. In the tropics, the sun and the moon can pass directly overhead. If both pass overhead at the same time there will be a solar eclipse directly overhead.

The eclipse of [July 11, 1991 was visible directly overhead](https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/in/mexico/tepic?iso=19910711), (to within a degree) and in totality, for observers in the Nayarit province in Mexico

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted

Comment: Indeed, and a good example of that, is the eclipse of July 11, 1991, it was visible directly overhead, and in totality, for observers in the Nayarit province in Mexico